# Не подключаются стили в Битриксе

Tags: javascript, html, css, битрикс

В шаблоне есть обычное меню (html + css + js). Вызовы CSS и JS воткнуты под `<head>`. Но почему то меню работает исключительно на главное страницы. На любых других пропадает связь html с CSS и JS

Comment: Здесь нет телепатов и гадалок. Покажите как вы подключаете Ваши стили, приведите код отвечающий за вывод меню (часть index.php и ссылку на pastebin с кодом шаблона компонента меню), добавьте скрин с настройками компонента меню, скрин структуры шаблона, и содержание файла из которого подключается меню. обычно что-то вроде `.menu-type.menu.php`. Ну и самое главное, что это за меню, главное для всех страниц или для раздела?

Answer (score 1):

Возможно на других страницах подключаются компоненты с собственными стилями, которые перезаписывают ваш стиль. Попробуйте у меню прописать другие стили и поправить вашу CSS